# CSS Div positioning

Tags: css

I have a Header/navigation bar on a site, it has a logo, navigation menu, and search box all in-line in that order

So the logo is on the left, followed by the nav menu and the the search box to the right.

The search box is aligned using `position: relative;` the problem is it is positioned relative to the nav menu which is the div before the search box.

The reason that is a problem, is because the nav menu can be of different sizes, depending on which menu items it is showing.

I need a reliable way to position my search box, is there a way to position a Div relative to a certain Div and not just the Div that is directly before it?

In the image the search box should be positioned over the sidebar, but like I mentioned the nav menu can be of different lengths so If I position relative X off of it, it will be different depending on the width of that menu
[image]

Comment: Can you paste some code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a wrapper  around your nav menu and give it a fixed width.

Answer (score 0):

Try having your nav and search inside of a single div, then use absolute positioning for the search.